# Retrieve data class members

Tags: kotlin

I need to check if any variables inside of my data class are null. To do this I need retrieve them first but I can't access them directly (e.g. myDataClass.name) because I need it to be generic. Is there a way to access these variables without directly naming them. For example, like accessing a member of an array (myArray[0]).

Comment: This sounds like the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: As stated: retrieve variables from the class dynamically. So something along the lines of myClass.members[0] instead of myClass.name.

Comment: The word you were looking for is "reflection": https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mechanism you're looking for is called "reflection" and it allows to introspect objects at runtime. You'll find a lot of information on the internet, but just to give you a link you may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful).

In your case you could do something like this:

```
data class MyDataClass(
    val first: String?,
    val second: String?,
    val third: Int?
)

fun main() {
    val a = MyDataClass("firstValue", "secondValue", 1)
    val b = MyDataClass("firstValue", null, null)

    printProperties(a)
    printProperties(b)
}

fun printProperties(target: MyDataClass) {
    val properties = target::class.memberProperties
    for (property in properties) {
        val value = property.getter.call(target)
        val propertyName = property.name
        println("$propertyName=$value")
    }
}
```

Note that for this code to work you must add `kotlin-reflect` package as a dependency.